# get previous date using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, gridview

My query is

```
SELECT 
    matno,
    MAT_NAME,
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [1/1/2014],
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=DateAdd("d", -1, ?),ORDCASES)) AS [previous_day] 
FROM invorder 
WHERE (invorder.strno =54009) OR ([invorder.deldate] IS NULL) 
GROUP BY  matno,MAT_NAME;
```

Here I can just check one before date of selected date,but if their are no records with previous date the I should decrement date by one more day and check until I find the records. Can someone help me how can I decrement and find the previous date?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:mysql], but your syntax looks like T-SQL.  Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the exact case, I would suggest an approach like:

```
SELECT MAX(date) 
FROM myTable
WHERE date < '2014-01-01' --> Replace this as needed
```

This would result in the previous date **with a record**. Without the need of checking each and every day by substraction.

I've tried to match your case, try this:

```
SELECT   invorder.matno,
         invorder.MAT_NAME,
         MAX(invorder.date) AS this_record_date,
         MAX(previous.date) AS prev_record_date
FROM     invorder 
JOIN     invorder AS previous 
                  ON invorder.matno = previous.matno 
                  AND invorder.strno = previous.strno 
                  AND invorder.date > previous.date
WHERE    invorder.strno =54009
GROUP BY invorder.matno, 
         invorder.MAT_NAME
```

This selects the maximum record by `date` of `strno` 54009, it's `matno`, `MAT_NAME` and `date`. This row is extended with the maximum date of the same `matno` and `strno` excluding the date we already selected (so pretty much the second most maximum date).

Comment: I dont need all the dates,I just need I previous date data to be displayed.I want previous date to be displayed under column header "previous_date"

Comment: @user3202126 I extended my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the effort,I tried above query but I am facing below error. 
Syntax error in FROM clause. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.